# Boxes Bug in 10.0.2.0

Tags: front-end, display, boxes

*Mathematica* 10.0.2.0, specifically:

10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)
ReleaseID 10.0.2.0 (5206630, 2014120404), 
PatchLevel 0

appears to have a bug in handling boxes. The application crashes pretty consistently with the following:

A cell with Style *DisplayFormula* and contents:

```
b
```

Copy the cell and, in front of the b, type Keyboard Entry [Esc]ee[Esc][Ctrl][6] to produce formatted e, the base of the natural log raised to a power. Note the ghost box in blue to the right of the true box for the power. Attempt to enter the power in the true box and ... crash.

This is small, specific and reproducible so may help uncover a bug.

Comment: The [tag:bugs] tag is not supposed to be added to a question until other people have confirmed your observations to be a genuine bug.

Comment: I recall having similar editing crashes some time ago. I forget exactly when. I reported at least one to WRI. For 10.0.2.0 in your case, I don't think they would care since it seems fixed in the current version. Your protocol did not produce a crash for me in V12.1 (Mac).